"Better luck next time"-mechanic in anydice?
I am trying to create an anydice function which adds a bonus-dice to the attack-roll pool every time the attack misses.
Say I have 4 attacks and roll to hit with 1d20+0d6, if I don't beat their AC of 10, I get to roll 1d20+1d6 to hit for my next attack, and should I miss again it's 1d20+2d6 on my next try, etc.
But as soon as I hit, I deal 1 damage and the bonus-dice count gets reset to 0d6.
After 4 attacks I should either have dealt 4 damage and not needed a single bonus-dice, dealt 0 damage and have accumulated 4 bonus dice, or have anything in between...
For reasons that elude me though my bonus-dice counter is stuck at 0 no matter what, and I supposedly only ever deal 1 damage. Does anybody have an idea what I might have gotten wrong?
function: attack HIT:n for DMG:n {
   loop Y over {1..4} {
       if HIT >= AC      {
          N:0
          result:SUM+DMG  }
       else               {
          N:N+1
          result:SUM      }
}}

N:0
AC:10
SUM:0

output[attack 1d20+Nd6 for 1] 

https://anydice.com/program/38d1e

Hi there and welcome to the stack. Is your question about the Lancer RPG or D&D 5e? You tagged it both.

The mechanic is from Rank 3 "Relentless" of the talent "Brutal" from the Lancer RPG. Technically it should function as only taking the highest of all the bonus-dice rolled. But I wanted to simplify the question for now... With that "keep-highest" function added I consider giving it as a feat to one of my DnD Players, possibly lowering the bonus-dice to d4s

There are a few issues here:

Setting result causes the function to return immediately.
You are also not accumulating into any variable: even if setting result didn't return immediately, each time you hit your replace the result with SUM (which is set to 0 and never changes) plus DMG, so you would only produce at most 1 damage regardless.
Here your attack roll will be "rolled" just once, not four times, then sent to the HIT parameter of the function and used for all four attacks. You can't solve this just by changing HIT to type die because AnyDice does not support probabilistic conditions in if statements.1 Basically, you need to make a function call for every attack in order to resolve it into a hit/miss that you can put into an if statement. (Rolling all the attacks at the same time doesn't work well here since you'd still need to account for an unknown number of bonus d6s.)
Likewise, your DMG is only rolled once because it is of type number. This doesn't matter if you do a flat amount of damage per hit, but for random damage you would want to have DMG be of type die instead. Alternatively, you could first determine the number of hits then roll damage using the d operator.
To take the highest of nd6 we can use the highest function. Fortunately, AnyDice treats the highest of 0 dice as 0 so we don't need to make a separate case for N = 0.

Probably the easiest approach is to use a recursive function:
set "maximum function depth" to 20

function: attack LASTHIT:n and ATTACKS:n more times vs AC:n bonus N:n {
 if ATTACKS = 0 {
  result: LASTHIT
 }
 if LASTHIT {
  N: 0
 } else {
  N: N + 1
 }
 result: LASTHIT + [attack d20 + [highest 1 of Nd6] >= AC and ATTACKS-1 more times vs AC bonus N]
}

function: attack ATTACKS:n times vs AC:n bonus N:n {
 result: [attack d20 + [highest 1 of Nd6] >= AC and ATTACKS-1 more times vs AC bonus N]
}

output [attack 4 times vs 10 bonus 0]d1

Link.
Here we start by feeding one attack roll to the function. Each recursive call evaluates the previous attack roll and calls for another attack, until we have no attacks left. After determining the number of hits, we roll that many damage dice and sum using the d operator.

1 To be clear, this is not a criticism of AnyDice. I think restricting probabilistic branching to function calls was a great choice:

The points at which branching happens are immediately obvious.
The computational cost is easier to estimate.
The behavior is closer to most other programming languages.
We don't have to worry about the distinction between probability distributions (dice) and random variables.


Thank you! This worked for me, turns out: Once you have one bonus-dice, it almost makes no difference for normal ACs. Could have realized that myself, but it's nice to see the hard numbers

After using your code as a basis for my the detailed circumstances, I came up with this btw https://anydice.com/program/38d40

Glad to help! Although, there is a wrinkle here: as I understand it, Reliable deals damage on a miss but should still count it as a miss and thus not reset Relentless, whereas the code as written would reset it since more than 0 damage was done. You could try postponing evaluating Reliable until the next recursive call, i.e. result: [highest of LASTHIT and MIN] + [repeat...

Ohhhh, you're so right, thank you!!
